# Powershell script that calls a variable inside of a file path?

Tags: powershell, ftp, directory, mkdir, invoke-command

Whenever creating an FTP folder for an FTP client in my company, I have to create two folders on two servers; server A and server B. I've tried to give an example below.

```
E:\FTP\CompanyName
E:\FTP\CompanyName\Incoming
E:\FTP\CompanyName\Outgoing
```

It would need to look like this on both servers. It isn't that hard to do manually, but I am wanting to learn Powershell, so why not automate a simple task? Here is what I currently have:

```
$Company = Read-Host 'Enter Company Name:'
$Credentials = Get-Credential

Write-Host 'Thank you! Creating client FTP folder on ServerA.' -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor White 

Invoke-Command ServerA {mkdir ("e:\ftp" + $Company + "\INCOMING")} -Credential $Credentials
Invoke-Command ServerA {mkdir ("e:\ftp" + $Company + "\OUTGOING")} -Credential $Credentials

Write-Host 'Done. Now creating duplicate folder on ServerB.' -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor White 

Invoke-Command ServerB {mkdir e:\ftp\$Company\INCOMING} -Credential $Credentials
Invoke-Command ServerB {mkdir e:\ftp\$Company\OUTGOING} -Credential $Credentials

Write-Host 'Done.' -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor White
```

We have a set of admin credentials that we use specifically for server access. The script asks for those credentials and then also asks the "CompanyName" is. In theory, I would like it to then apply that variable to the "CompanyName" section of the file path.

I tried it two different ways in the script, just to test. They both completely skip the variable and just create an incoming and outgoing folder in E:\ftp. What am I missing here?

Any other advice on how to clean up my script is welcome as well. I've learned a lot doing this, but there is quite a bit more to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$company` does not exist in the session on the other server so it can´t be used to create the folder like you want.

You can pass your variable by using the `-Argumentlist` parameter of `Invoke-Command` like this:

```
Invoke-Command ServerA {mkdir ("e:\ftp" + $args[0] + "\INCOMING")} -ArgumentList $Company -Credential $Credentials
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look closer at the whole Argument side of things. I didn't even realize that the variable wouldn't exist on the other server, but that makes sense now that it has been pointed out to me. When I pass the variable though (lets say I define the variable as "testCompany"), it creates a folder directly on E: called "ftptestCompany"? I am assuming it is taking the ftp part of e:\ftp and thinking it is part of the name. I'll test inserting an extra \ in the mkdir command.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once, my solution was something like:

```
Invoke-Command ServerA {param($Company) "mkdir e:\ftp\$Company\INCOMING"} -ArgumentList $Company -Credential $Credentials 
Invoke-Command ServerA {param($Company) "mkdir e:\ftp\$Company\OUTGOING"} -ArgumentList $Company -Credential $Credentials
```

The `param` block is used to pass local values to the command that is being invoked in remote session.

Is explained in more detail in: [How to pass arguments for remote commands](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/12/29/arguments-for-remote-commands.aspx)

The other solution using `$args[0]` is also explained there.